# Local Storage item loading in as string when I need it to be an integer

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently trying to allow users to input a value that is then added to a total and then locally stored. I want to allow the user to load their previous total, and then add more to it through the same input.

What's actually happening is that when the user loads onto the page, the previously stored value is loaded in as a string. I'm unsure as to how to change this to an integer so as the user can then add another integer to it. This updated total then needs to be displayed to a html element.

```
//Load current total or set to 0
var calories = localStorage.getItem("calorieCount") || 0;
//Display current total
$('[id=calorieCount]').html(calories);

//On add
$('#calorie-add').click(function () {
      //Take current total and add user input
      calories += parseInt(document.getElementById('adjust-input').value);
      //Update current total to local storage
      localStorage.setItem('calorieCount', calories);
      //Display new total
      $('[id=calorieCount]').html(calories);
    });
```

I understand that anything that is locally stored is stored as a string, but I've seen people mentioning parsing it into an integer and allowing users to manipulate the number. But I'm unsure as to how they've achieved this.

Any help is greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the local storage value as an int the first time you load it like this:

```
var calories = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("calorieCount")) || 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, what you can do is parse the localStorage.getItem("calorieCount") string as a number using the Number() function, change the value based on user's input, and then save the new value to localStorage. Try using this code:

```
var calories = Number(localStorage.getItem("calorieCount")) || 0;
$('[id=calorieCount]').html(calories);
$('#calorie-add').click(function () {
      calories += Number(document.getElementById('adjust-input').value);
      //Update current total to local storage
      localStorage.setItem('calorieCount', calories);
      //Display new total
      $('[id=calorieCount]').html(calories);
    });
```